# i2c address not detected while trying to use Adafruit VL53L0X Time of Flight Distance Sensor

Tags: i2c, breadboard

I have a Raspberry Pi 4. I am using the Adafruit VL53L0X Time of Flight Distance Sensor. I have connected a T-Cobbler to a breadboard and attached that to my Raspberry Pi. The sensor is wired correctly according to a video my teacher provided. I installed what my teacher told be to install for the sensor correctly. However, when I try to run code. I get a very long error and when I run "sudo i2cdetect -y 1" no number shows up, it's a blank field. I am very new to this and my teacher is not responding. ANY feedback is appreciated, thanks.

https://photos.app.goo.gl/JbXCDT3Hxr8E6Lkn7 --Wiring
https://photos.app.goo.gl/wnShijCAVXEF7az98 --Error Message
https://photos.app.goo.gl/gLP3mc6ZVpCgBGSv7 --sudo i2cdetect -y 1 message

Comment: Where is the error message?  Where is a photo of the wiring?  Where is the code you are using?  Don't make us guess.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize the images were too big to send. These links should work

Comment: this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62757687/raspberry-pi-4-i2c-bus-not-working-correctly/62786449#62786449

Comment: please add the error message text to your post ... a picture of text cannot be copied and searched on the internet

Answer (score 0):

The `i2cdetect` shows that you have not connected the device to the I2C bus.

Check and redo your wiring (I can't see anything obviously wrong but the photo is not detailed enough to see what is connected to what).

Comment: I appreciate the comment. What is the i2c bus?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/raspberry-pi-spi-and-i2c-tutorial/all

Answer (score 0):

The "OSError: [Errno 121] remote I/O error" typically indicates a communication problem between the Raspberry Pi and the sensor.Check that the I2C interface on the Raspberry Pi is enabled. You can do this using the **raspi-config** tool or by editing the **/boot/config.txt** file.